# how to put a # in front of every line inside a pair of parenthese with RegEx?

Tags: regex

I want to change this

```
@author(
line 1
line 2
line 3
)
```

to the following with RegEx.

```
@author(
#line 1
#line 2
#line 3
)
```

I can sth like this `^@author\([^]]+\n\)` to query the block, how to place the # in front of each line?

Comment: What programming language (PHP?) or tool (Notepad++?) are you using?

Comment: [`^([^()]+?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/HEwWz0/1) would do it.

Comment: Use '^(?=line)' as regex and replace with '#' (use multiline option)

Comment: If infinite lookbehinds are supported `(?<=^@author\(\r?\n[^()]*)[^(\r\n)]+\r?\n(?=[^()]*\))` https://regex101.com/r/6Mse5P/1

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the PCRE (PHP) regex engine, you can use the regular expression

```
^([^)@].*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bfQN3G/1/)

The regex is performing the following operations:

```
^      # match beginning of line
(      # begin capture group 1
[^)@]  # match a character other than ')' and ']'
.*     # match 0+ chars to the end of the line
)      # end capture group 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use a PCRE-based regex environment, you could search for

`(@author\(\n|\G(?!\A).*+\n(?!\)))`

and replace matches with

`$1#`

. See an explanation for [this expression at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Ge05yo/1).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a programming language that supports the `\G` anchor, you might use

```
(?:(^@author\((?=[^()]*\))\r?\n|\G(?!^))([^()\r\n]+\r?\n))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LwnFVN/1/)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups

```
$1#$2
```

If an [infinite repetition in a lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width) is supported , you might use

```
(?<=^@author\(\r?\n[^()]*)[^(\r\n)]+\r?\n(?=[^()]*\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Mse5P/1)

In the replacement use the full match prepended with `#`